# Regex for matching multiple lines in one go but ignoring the start token

Tags: regex

I would like to match the following using regex as **one single match group** but ignore the `>` starting on each line.

```
> [!question]- Describe the flow of data within a Transformer during training
> Information
> More information
```

See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhLwe.jpg) to view the content I'm trying to match in one match group (it is underlined)

Is this possible? If so, does anyone have any pointers on how to write a regex that accomplishes this?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. If you are parsing Markdown, it's best to use a full-fledged Markdown parser.

Comment: Are you trying to implement this in any particular programming language?

Comment: My use case is quite niche so I wouldn't say a specific programming language - but essentially if it works in regex101 it should work for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is by using a non-capturing group for the undesired character:

```
(?:> )?(.*)
```

**Example:**

[image: Regex working as described]

A working demonstration can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/SOqYr8/1). if you also want to ignore the `[!question]` text like in the initial image, it gets a little more complex:

```
(?:> (?:\[[^\]]*?\](?:- )?)?)?(.*)
```

**Example:**

[image: Regex working as desired]

That regex, which can be seen working [here](https://regex101.com/r/oWgCdN/1), operates by optionally including the format for the question markdown in the initial non-capture group of each line.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for the suggestion! It looks great, the only issue is that while it ignores the leading `> `, the main thing I'm trying to do is have it all within one single match group (whereas the solution you provided leads to 3 match groups, one on each line). The reason for this is that I am building a parser that converts markdown to flashcards, and so one single match group corresponds to the front of the card (and the second match group not shown corresponds to the back). Thanks again, any suggestions from here?

Comment: @Salami check again, the match group contains all of the green text, which is what was requested. That is why the `$1` in the substitution is there, to demonstrate the contents of the first capture group.